# Print only one line at a time from text file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, text-processing

how can I print or display only word from a text file at a time.
When I run my script it should only display each word from the text file one by one, but only display that word.

This is what I have done, but it displays each word on separate line, but it shows all of them:

```
FS=$'\n'      
for j in `cat read`
do
    echo "$j"
done
```

I want the output to look something like this:

```
root@matrix:~> first word  ---> this word disappear when second is displayed
root@matrix:~> second word ---> this disappear when third is displayed
root@matrix:~> third word  ---> this disappear when fourth is displayed and continues like this to the end of the file!
```

Comment: I am sure you could write an awk script to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sleep` and `clear` commands in your script as following:

```
for word in $(< read)
do
    echo "$word"
    sleep 1
    clear
done
```

#### Explanation:

The `sleep` command make delay for a specified amount of time (in seconds). With `sleep 1` delay would be for 1 second. You can change for more time delay by incrementing the second parameter or for delaying less than 1 second divide it to low units; Like `sleep .1` for 1/10 second delay or `sleep .001` for 1/1000 second delay and etc.

The `clear` command clear the terminal screen.

#### Even better you can do this through below `awk` command:

```
awk '{i=1; while(i<=NF){ print $((i++)); system("sleep 1; clear") }}' read
```

#### Explanation:

In `awk`, the `NF` specifies **the total number of fields** in the current input record/line, so by using a variable as a counter (`i`) and looping over it, we are printing all of them from 1st position to the end of them (`NF`). Then by using the `system("sleep 1; clear")` part, we are telling to `awk` to calling the system commands to sleeping for 1 second and clearing the screen.

---

In above we are displaying the input file as word by word. If you are going to display it line by line add `IFS=$'\n'` in the script like:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for word in $(< read)
do
    echo "$word"
    sleep 1
    clear
done
```

And change the `awk` command like:

```
awk '{ $0; system("sleep 1; clear") }1' read
```

- `$0` specifies the current line. and the `1` on end enables the default `awk`'s *print* command.

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem. Can you also tell me how do I display 120 or more words in one minutes!

Comment: @HassenFatima decrease the second to low unit by `sleep .1` (it means each word/line per 1/10 second) or `sleep .001` (means each word/line in 1/1000 second) and lower by .00000000000...1

Answer (score 4):

With `bash`, I'd do:

```
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line
do
    printf "%-${COLUMNS}s\r" "$line"
    sleep 1
done < file
```

By using the carriage return (`\r`) instead of line feed (`\n`), you can overwrite the current line. The `-${COLUMNS}` pads the output with spaces so that previous lines are completely overwritten.

For a per-word solution, I think a double loop is needed:

```
while read -ra line
do 
    for word in "${line[@]}"
    do
        printf "%-${COLUMNS}s\r" "$word"
        sleep 1
    done
done < file
```

Comment: I thought OP's input file has more than one word in each line :/

Comment: @KasiyA Hmmm. I assumed that OP meant `IFS` and not `FS` in the first line, in which case, it goes line by line.

Comment: But your script will fails if the first word in fist line was long-length and second word in next line was small-length than previous shown line. run your script on [this input as example](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10645006/)

Comment: @KasiyA fixed that.