# Display specific characters in specific time from a text file

Tags: bash, scripts

How can I display a specific number of words or characters in a given time using a loop.
 Lets say I want to display 120 words in one minute.

Here is the loop i have tried:

```
FS=$'\n'
for j in `cat $1`;
do
        echo "$j";
        sleep  1;
        clear;
done
```

This one only takes one second but does not work for 120 words in one minute or similar. How can I do this?

Comment: So what is your issue exactly? are you asking about the relationship between *words per minute* and *seconds per word*?

Comment: I want the script to display 120 words from a text file of my choice in one minute. If I say "scriptname speed textfilename" the script should display 120 words using that loop in one minute. "Scriptone 120 file1.txt"

Answer (score 2):

The sleep command make delay for a specified amount of time (in seconds). With `sleep 1` delay would be for 1 second (one word per second). You can change for more time delay by incrementing the second parameter or for delaying less than 1 second divide it to low units; Like `sleep .1` for 1/10 second delay or `sleep .001` for 1/1000 second delay and etc.

So if you want to display 120 words per minute you can use `sleep .5` (that means display each word in 0.5 second which also means 120 words in a minute)

And your final script would be as following:

```
#!/bin/bash

for word in $(< "$2");
do
    echo "$word";
    sleep  $1;
    clear;
done
```

Save the script named `scriptname.sh` and make it as executable by `chmod +x scriptname.sh` and then run the script with `./scriptname.sh .5 infile`

Comment: relates to this answer [Print only one line at a time from text file](http://askubuntu.com/a/599601/283843)

Answer (score 0):

It's a frequent practice to use `while read line ; do . . .; done` structure in bash to read file line by line. Assuming your input file has one word per line, it's easy to do something like this:

```
while read line; do printf "%s\n" "$line" ; sleep 3; done < input.txt
```

Python can do this quite easily:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys,time
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line.strip()
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Usage:

```
python print_with_delay.py <input.txt
```