# open and save links in firefox from txt file

Tags: command-line, scripts, dash-shell

I have a txt file with several links (one per line) and I need to open each of these links (one at a time) in firefox, save the file and go to the next link (next line of the txt file). how can I do this?

I tried the script below without success (the link of the first line of the txt opens in firefox and stops)

```
IFS=$'\n'
for link in $(< txt-file)
do
    firefox -new-window "$link"
    sleep 5s
    xdotool key "Ctrl+s"
    sleep 5s
    xdotool key "KP_Enter"
    sleep 2s
    xdotool key "KP_Enter"
    sleep 2s
    xdotool key "Ctrl+w"
    sleep 1s
done
```

[script based on the answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599570/print-only-one-line-at-a-time-from-text-file)

txt-file

```
www.example.com/fdsffsffsd
www.example.com/fdhgjhkujkuk
www.example.com/ggfghgghjhuiklol
```

Comment: Probably the issue is that `firefox -new-window "$link"` is executed in the shell foreground, so the next line of your script won't be executed until it is closed. I can't test it, but try starting it in the background (by appending `&`). However I suspect there are cleaner ways of accomplishing your task.

Comment: Is it really neccessary to use Firefox to do this? I'd use `wget` command which has `--input-file` option, a single command would do the task.

Comment: @steeldriver & made the script work, thanks! this message appears in the terminal "### !!! [Parent] [RunMessage] Error: Channel error: cannot send / recv", but the link for each line of the txt is opened and saved

Comment: @mook765 the links require authentication that wget cannot handle